# Fatal error: Class 'Mage_Elitetrial_Helper_Data' not found in Magento 1.9

Tags: magento

I am facing the below error

> Fatal error:  Class 'Mage_Elitetrial_Helper_Data' not found in
>   /home3/o1b9z2k1/public_html/mysite/app/Mage.php on line 547

Please help me.

Thank you!

Comment: Please share more info. What is the name of your module (Namespace_Module)? Where is this error happening? Magento fails to autoload your helper, but there are couple of reasons why is this happening. If you just removed a module, it could be that all you have to do is flush cache.

Answer (score 0):

go to app/code/local/Elitetrial/Helper/ folder and create a file with the name of Data.php and write below code

```
<?php
class Mage_Elitetrial_Helper_Data extends Mage_Core_Helper_Abstract
{

}
```